# Library or ideas to create a image editor on android

Tags: android, image-editor

I need to load a image and create some annotation on top of it.
I want to be able to put rectangles and text blocks on the image area and drag and drop them.
Something like diamont lite (only with a user defined image background).
To see a screen of diamond like use this link :

http://br.androlib.com/android.application.com-welant-dianoid-lite-zCzxj.aspx

I was not able to find any library to make this.
But what kind of classes should I use to implement this ? I am doing some tests here but I am not able to get a smooth editing.

Comment: I'm not sure what I was supposed to see at the link. Can you provide a different link, or specify what I should be seeing on the page?

Comment: On the page we have a screenshot of Dianoid (a diagram editor to android). I just send the link to show the type of elements I want to be able to add on my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a library to it.
But it can be done using a ImageSurfaceView.
I can use the onDraw and onTouchEvent methods to do what I need.